# tap-bridge-tap : No LACP

Tags: bridge, qemu, lacp

I have two switches connected via TAP interfaces.
Each Virtual Switch port is connected to an individual TAP port and the TAP ports are joined via a Bridge.

```
SW1-port1 = TAP 11 <== BR121 ==> TAP 21 = SW2-port1
SW1-port2 = TAP 12 <== BR122 ==> TAP 22 = SW2=port2
```

If I configure the Switch ports as normal layer 3, they can ping each other, which means the setup above is working, however LACP packets get dropped and I cannot establish a port channel between the two (for educational purposes).

I can see LACP packets generated by the locally connected switch if I "tcpdump" the TAP interface, but somehow the LACP packet does not make it to the other end (to the other TAP I/F).

Could it be the Bridge absorbing the LACP packet?
Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks,
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, LACP uses the group address 01:80:C2:00:00:02, which is in the "do not relay" range: any 802.1D-compliant bridge [must not forward](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/tut/macgrp.pdf) these frames.

While Linux bridges allow configuring exceptions to this (via [group_fwd_mask](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net)), this feature is meant for higher level protocols such as LLDP or 802.1X and explicitly refuses to add a bypass for the STP/LACP address.

(I think this makes a lot of sense, because these protocols are specifically meant to be used between *two* peers on opposite ends of a direct link, and would malfunction in various ways otherwise.)

Bridges classified as [two-port MAC relays](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2008/aj-messenger-tpmr-status-1207-v2.pdf) would be an exception: as they link exactly two interfaces, they can be transparent to LACP. However, as far as I know there is no native method of telling a Linux bridge to act as one.

It *could* be done using a userspace program to move frames between two interfaces, such as `socat`.

Alternatively you could run LACP between each of your vswitches *and the Linux host* (using either the bonding or teaming drivers), and then put the bridge *on top* of the two LAGs (bond interfaces).

Comment: Hi Grawity, that is a very good explanation and it makes perfect sense. I will look into the SOCAT option.